# Using VBA to run WinSCP script

Tags: excel, vba, cmd, winscp

I am able to download files from SFTP in `CMD` window, by using following code:

```
WinSCP.com
# Connect to the host and login using password
open user:pw@address
# get all the files in the remote directory and download them to a specific local directory
lcd C:\Users\xx\Desktop
get *.xlsx
# Close and terminate the session
exit
```

I searched online and found out that I can put these codes in a `bat` file and use

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /c C:\Users\xx\Desktop\WinSCPGet.bat", 1)
```

However, only the first line of the bat file `WinSCP.com` is being executed. It will pop up the `cmd` window, showing this, without doing anything else.
[image]

How to execute all the lines at one time?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have is not a Windows batch file. It's one Windows command followed by WinSCP commands. The first command runs `winscp.com` application, which then sits and waits for input. If you eventually close it, Windows command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) will carry on executing the remaining commands, failing most, as they are not Windows commands. See also [WinSCP script not executing in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31945476/850848) and WinSCP FAQ [Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)

So you either have to save the commands (`open` to `exit`) to a WinSCP script file (say `script.txt`) and execute the script using the [`/script` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting):

```
Call Shell("C:\path\winscp.com /ini=nul /script=c:\path\script.txt")
```

Alternatively, specify all commands on WinSCP command line, using the [`/command` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting):

```
Call Shell("C:\path\winscp.com /ini=nul /command ""open user:pw@address"" ""lcd C:\Users\xx\Desktop"" ""get *.xlsx"" ""exit""")
```

Regarding the quotes: With the `/command` switch, you have to enclose each command to double-quotes. In VBA string, to use a double-quote, you have to escape it by doubling it.

---

Also note that you generally should use the [`/ini=nul` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#configuration) to [isolate the WinSCP script run from your WinSCP configuration](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#configuration). This way you can also make sure that the script will run on other machines. Your script won't, as it lacks the [`-hostkey` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey) to [verify the SSH host key fingerprint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey). Using the `/ini=nul` will help you realize that.

---

You can have [WinSCP GUI generate complete command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) (including the `-hostkey`) for you.

See also [Automating  file transfers to SFTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

Answer (score 3):

I like this small and compact procedure, and use it in my own projects. No temp-files required. Fast and reliable.

Parse a string `src` (an absolute filepath) to `uploadImageByFTP`. Etc. `C:\Users\user\Desktop\image.jpg`, and the file will be uploaded.

Replace:

- `<username>` with FTP-User
- `<password>` with FTP-Password
- `<hostname>` with FTP-hostname (etc. example.com)
- `<WinSCP.com path>` with path on your WinSCP-client (etc. `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com`. **Caution**: `WinSCP.com` and not `WinSCP.exe`)
- `<FTP-path>` with path on your FTP-client (etc. `/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads`)

```
Sub uploadImageByFTP(src As String)
    Dim script As Object: Set script = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

    'Not empty
    If (src <> vbNullString) Then

       'Execute script 
        script.Run _
            """<WinSCP.com path>"" " + _
            "/ini=nul " + _
            "/command " + _
            """open ftp://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/"" " + _
            """cd <FTP-path>"" " + _
            """put " & """""" & src & """""" & """ " + _
            """close"" " + _
            """exit""", windowStyle, waitOnReturn

    End If

End Sub
```

`WScript.Shell` is more powerful than the default `Shell()`, as you can append a  `waitOnReturn`-command; this tells VBA, that further execution isn't allowed before the file(s) have been uploaded to the FTP-server.

Change `windowStyle` to 0, if you don't like the command prompt to open on each execution.