# How to use Excel VBA to run WinSCP Script?

Tags: vba, excel, winscp

I wrote a WinSCP script that upload a local file to a SFTP site. The script is saved into .txt:

```
WinSCP.com
open sftp://username:password@address
cd /export/home/Desktop/Temp
put C:\Users\Dekstop\JPMC\a.xlsx
close
exit
```

Then I look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280733/using-vba-to-run-winscp-script) and write this code into Excel VBA:

```
Sub RunWinScp()
Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /ini=nul/script=C:\Users\Desktop\WinSCPGetNew.txt")
End Sub
```

But when I try to run it, nothing happens. There is no error, but the file is not transferred correctly neither. Could someone please help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to enclose the path to `winscp.com` with double quotes, as it contains spaces
- You need a space between the `/ini=nul` and `/script=...`

```
Call Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"" /ini=nul /script=C:\Users\Desktop\WinSCPGetNew.txt")
```

- Remove the `winscp.com` at the beginning of your `WinSCPGetNew.txt` script. There's no `winscp.com` command in WinSCP. You already run `WinSCP.com` by the `Shell` function in VBA. This is actually already covered in the question you link to yourself: [Using VBA to run WinSCP script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37280733/850848).

Though you better specify the commands on WinSCP command-line using the [`/command` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting) to avoid a need to for a separate commands file:

```
Call Shell( _
    """C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"" " + _
    "/ini=nul " + _
    "/command " + _
    """open sftp://username:password@example.com/"" " + _
    """cd /export/home/Desktop/Temp"" " + _
    """put C:\users\Desktop\JPMC\a.xlsx"" " + _
    """close"" " + _
    """exit""")
```