# Sync local and remote file using VBA and WinSCP

Tags: excel, vba, shell, vbscript, winscp

I'm trying to auto sync local files with a server using WinSCP. I'm getting the following script error:

[image]

Here is my vba code:

```
Public Sub pullwinscp()
Shell "wscript C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\SyncSftp.vbs", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

And here is the script I'm trying to call (saved as .vbs):

```
open sftp://User:Password@webaddress.org -hostkey="aaaaa-aaa2 aaaaa256 7a:4a:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:a1:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
synchronize local C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\test /home/FTP/Acct Hourly Acctg
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: That ISN'T a .vbs file.

Comment: As VBS can be pasted into VBA (VBS code is legal VBA code) why would you use a separate vbs file.

Comment: ok, can you show me how this would look in vba?

Comment: The exact same as VBS. But that in not a VBS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ".vbs" is not VBScript code. That's [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

To run WinSCP script from VBA, use:

```
Call Shell("C:\path\winscp.com /ini=nul /script=c:\path\SyncSftp.txt")
```

(after you rename `SyncSftp.vbs` to `SyncSftp.txt`, as it's not VBScript)

See also [Using VBA to run WinSCP script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37280733/850848).

Comment: I've tried this several different ways and keep getting "file not found". here is how my last attempt looks:   Call Shell("C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\Sync.txt\winscp.com /ini=nul /script=C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\Sync.txt")   Probably way off, I'm new at this.

Comment: `C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\Sync.txt\winscp.com` looks like a nonsense, if `C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\Sync.txt` is a file. You need to use a path to `winscp.com` - For example `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com` - in which case you need to wrap it to double-quotes as it contains spaces (and the double-quotes  need to be doubled in VBA string).

Comment: Martin, when the cmd screen pops up it says searching for host and then times out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your WinSCP command-line/script work, when you execute it from command-line (`cmd`)?

Comment: It seems I'm unable to enter anything into the console command-line. When my code runs, the console pops up and reads:  "option batch abort;
option confirm off; searching for host..." and then times out. I tried double quotation marks and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: finally got to use my script in the cmd line and it says "too many parameters for cmd synchronize".

Comment: As the second path contains a space, it needs to be surrounded by double-quotes: `synchronize local C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\test "/home/FTP/Acct Hourly Acctg"`

Comment: now its saying "host does not exist". I'll keep playing with it. Thank you Martin

Comment: How can it now fail on `open` command already, when it previously passed it and failed on `synchronize`? You must have changed something.

Comment: finally got it! Thanks again

Comment: Martin, I am trying to implement this at work where we have shared network folders. When I run script it fails to update the local folder that resides on our shared network. Any suggestions? open sftp://passwork:username@xxx.xxx.x.xx/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:82:40:be"
synchronize local S:\sharednetworkpath\WinSCP\ftpfiles "/Home/MC FTP/MC Hourly Acctg/"
exit

Comment: Looks good. Consider asking a new proper question with details on your problem, including a session log file.